# How does openssl construct the derived key from password with PBKDF2?

Tags: openssl, pbkdf2

I'm working on a Java module to decrypt messages encrypted by openssl,

```
openssl aes-256-cbc -k *** -a -pbkdf2 -iter 1 -md sha256
```

but without success.

After some investigation, the problem was found that I can't get the correct KEY and IV from a given passphrase and the salt.

Here is the code:

```
$ openssl aes-256-cbc -k hi -a -S 4142434445464748 -md sha256 -pbkdf2 -iter 1 -P
salt=4142434445464748
key=187DC06E1AF1278348E5EFE761FDE3133DF42B03CF64E1B286E50E58238AEFB5
iv =1949A8BB58205A5C04BB28AD1947016C

$ echo hiABCDEFGH | hd
00000000  68 69 41 42 43 44 45 46  47 48 0a                 |hiABCDEFGH.|
0000000b

$ echo -n hiABCDEFGH | sha256sum 
8c8a825dbab83fbe7fb58552e26bb98aa3af20e7e6294e04ae6422a86906606b  -
```

According to [EVP_BytesToKey](https://linux.die.net/man/3/evp_bytestokey) function,

> Key Derivation Algorithm
>
> The key and IV is derived by concatenating D_1, D_2, etc until enough data is available for the key and IV . D_i is defined as:
>
> D_i = HASH^count(D_(i-1) || data || salt)
> where || denotes concatentaion, D_0 is empty, HASH is the digest algorithm in use, **HASH^1(data) is simply HASH (data)**, HASH^2(data) is HASH ( HASH (data)) and so on.

so, for a single iteration, the key should be:

```
KEY = SHA256(password || salt)
```

that is `8c8a825d`... However, the result from openssl is `187DC06E`...

So, how does openssl compute the derived key?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used the "-pbkdf2" flag which means you are using the PBKDF2 a key derivation function (KDF) not the legacy KDF implemented `EVP_BytesToKey`.

PBKDF2 is defined in RFC 2898 here:
https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2898.txt

The relevant OpenSSL function is documented here:
https://www.openssl.org/docs/man1.1.1/man3/PKCS5_PBKDF2_HMAC.html

The RFC above refers to a pseudo-random function (PRF). Since you have specified a digest of SHA256, the PRF used is HMAC-SHA256 with the password as the key.